# Moving a SQL Server database from one machine to another

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

I am migrating a web application from one physical server to another server. Part of this process is moving a database instance from the old server to the new one. I was attempting to do this by creating a backup of the instance on the old machine, and restoring it to the server on the new one. However, when I select the `.bak` file as the device in the restore window, there is no option to hit OK or do anything.

[Here is how it looks in Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7omX.png)

The old machine is running SQL Server 2014, while our new server is running 2017.

Comment: can you show us a screenshot of this ?

Comment: I edited the post and added one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I select the .bak file as the device in the restore window, there is no option to hit OK or do anything.

You don't *need* the SSMS backup/restore dialog to restore the backup.  Just copy the .bak file to a location on the new server that your SQL instance can read, and in a new query window run a command like:

```
restore database MyDatabase from disk='c:\temp\MyDatabase.bak'
```

Comment: After running this query, I get a message stating "User does not have permission to restore database." I am not very familiar with the way SQL handles permissions in these kinds of migrations. What kind of steps do I need to take? Is it because I am using Windows Logins on the new server?

Comment: Your Windows Login should be a member of the `sysadmin` fixed server role, or have the `CREATE DATABASE` permission. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to leave them both running then use SQL Server Enterprise Manager "Copy Data base" feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

Once the data is copied, you can shut down the old server and then rename the new server if necessary.